# Delta Migration: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration, data-migration-tool, delta-migration

I have successfully done data migration.

After migration, we placed order, create product and test everything.
Now when we trying to run delta migration (also tried `-a` it is giving error like:

[image]

Its seems issue with related product link

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I am also getting an exact error, did you solve this? @Pawan

Comment: @zus, please check my answer and let me know if works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Solution, It was due to related products.

After migration, We created product in Magento 1 and assign related product to those products.

> Issue was `related products` assignment in magento 1

When We removed, related product from Magento 1 for newly products, above error has gone!

after migration we again assign related product in Magento 2

Hope above will help to others!